# bulk import pdf files into oracle table

Tags: oracle, pdf, upload, bulk

i have multiple folders on my disk and each folder has  pdf files (4 files in each folder). How can i insert files in each folder in oracle table rows. the folder name will make primary key (being unique social svc #). i have used code as is from this [link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/import-blob) but i get following error:-

```
  ora-22285 non-existent directory or file for fileopen operation
  ora-06512 at sys.dbns_lob line 805
```

i ve also granted all permissions on the directory to my user with command:-

```
  grant all on directory blob_dir to testuser
```

pl tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Have you done any research, because there are tons or examples - https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9536889900346329947

Comment: what type of column are you going to use to store PDF file?

Answer (score 1):

if you going to use BLOB data type then you can upload data from external file using SQL*Loader. In case you are going to use BFILE then you just need to copy files into Oracle Server file system and grant access to it via DIRECTORY object with READ privelege. BFILE provides read only access to external files via SQL.

Comment: i ve added more details in my question for ur kind perusal please and my table has BLOB data type to save pdf file.

Comment: pl chk my amended question @Rusty